# How to stop all the IN/OUT flows in Marklogic Database

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I want to stop all the IN/OUT flows in marklogic, It includes both ingestion and harmonization

Comment: What do you mean with `stop`? Do you mean interrupt any running flows, or disable all flows from running?

Comment: Disable all flows from running